# Access Associating Methods with Node in Treetop

Tags: ruby, parsing, dsl, treetop

With the grammar defined as below, why I keep get error while try to access the `val` method of nodes created by rule `key`?

The error message is

```
(eval):168:in `val': undefined local variable or method `key'
for #<Treetop::Runtime::SyntaxNode:0x00000101b1e160> (NameError)
```

The grammar is

```
grammar Command
  rule create_command
    'create' space pair {
      def val
        pair.val
      end
    }
  end

  rule pair
    key space? '=' space? '"' value '"' {
      def val
        { key.val => value.val }
      end
    }
  end

  rule key
    [A-Za-z_] [A-Za-z0-9_]* {
      def val
        key.to_sym
      end
    }
  end

  rule value
    ('\\"' / [^"])+ {
      def val
        value.to_s
      end
    }
  end

  rule space
    [ \t]+
  end
end
```

The test code is

```
require 'treetop'
Treetop.load "command"
p = CommandParser.new
r = p.parse 'create name = "foobar"'
p r.val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the contents of the rule itself through `text_value`. The grammar:

```ruby
grammar Command

  rule create_command
    'create' space pair {
      def val
        pair.val
      end
    }
  end

  rule pair
    key space? '=' space? '"' value '"' {
      def val
        { key.val => value.val }
      end
    }
  end

  rule key
    [A-Za-z_] [A-Za-z0-9_]* {
      def val
        text_value
      end
    }
  end

  rule value
    ('\\"' / [^"])+ {
      def val
        text_value
      end
    }
  end

  rule space
    [ \t]+
  end

end
```

which can be tested with:

```ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'treetop'
require 'polyglot'
require 'command'

parser = CommandParser.new
pair = parser.parse('create name = "foobar"').val
print pair['name'], "\n"
```

and will print:

```
foobar
```

to the console.